# Как удалить элемент массива в зависимости от последнего символа предыдущего элемента?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте!Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка:

```
 punctum='!?.'

 for a in range(len(words)):
        #этот цикл должен брать слово а в массиве words, проверять,  
        #есть ли в слове перед ним (b) на конце точка,вопр.или 
        # воскл. знак, и, если он там есть, удалить слово а
        b=words[a+1]
        if words[a][-1] in punctum:
            del words[b]
```

нужно, чтобы в массиве ['словоа', 'словоб.', 'словов', 'словог'] удалилось словов :(

Comment: Мрак. `словоА словоБ. словоВ словоГ` -- надо удалить словоВ и словоГ (потому что после удаления словоВ перед словоГ будет словоБ. (с точкой). Так? (т.е. все слова после слова с `?!.` удаляются?

Comment: Вы вообще этот код запускали? У вас b -- это сначала слово, а затем индекс в списке words; кроме этого, в строчке b = words[a + 1] у вас выход за пределы списка. Ну и самое главное -- после удаления нескольких слов, исходный range остается прежним, а значит последние индексы в нем будут невалидные.

Answer (score 4):

Лучше создать новый массив-список и копировать элементы туда, чем менять старый. Вообще есть много способов фильтровать массивы. Пример: отбираем все строки, непосредственно следующие за строкой, оканчивающейся на ! или ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

test = ".!?"
before = ["1.","2","3!","4","5?","6","7"]
after = []

for a, b in zip(before, before[1:]):
        if a[-1] in test:
                after.append(b)

print after
```

Проверка

> ['2', '4', '6']

Comment: Идея правильная, только по-моему исходная задача решается так:

    after.append(before[0])
    for a, b in zip(before, before[1:]):
        if a[-1] not in test:
            after.append(b)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
class PunctuationFilter:
    def __init__(self, chars):
        self.skip = False
        self.chars = chars

    def __call__(self, x):
        if self.skip:
            self.skip = False
            return False

        if x[-1] in self.chars:
            self.skip = True

        return True

filtred = filter(PunctuationFilter('.?!'), ['словоа', 'словоб.', 'словов', 'словог'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
>>> punctuation_marks = ('!', '?', '.')
>>> words = ['one', 'two!', 'three?', 'four.']
>>> words = [word for word in words if not word.endswith(punctuation_marks)]
>>> words
... ['one']
```

[Документация](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith)